# Can I buy Rock Band 3 now and get the songs into Rock Band 4?

Tags: ps3, ps4, rock-band-3, rock-band-4

I have just purchased Rock Band 4 for PS4.  I have never owned any of the previous games in this console family.

I'm feeling rather constrained by the track list, and would like to add the Rock Band 3 tracks to the mix.  I have found [information on how to do this](http://www.polygon.com/2015/12/16/10299950/rock-band-4-3-song-export-import).

But the only copies of the game still available are pre-owned.  Can the above steps be performed if the game is purchased pre-owned?  Can they be done if I only bought the game as of now (as opposed to when the game was released)?

Comment: As I understand it, you can still export the songs from RB3.  You can even use a used copy of RB3 to export the songs.  Whether it is new or used, you have to pay the song export fee ($15, I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I picked up the game second hand.  The problem I then had was I couldn't get the export to activate.  (I tried the steps [here](http://forums.harmonixmusic.com/discussion/comment/5234669/#Comment_5234669) as well.)   Finally, I contacted Harmonix support; they asked for evidence of my purchase (in my case "Take a photo of the disc along with your PSN ID written on a piece of paper") and then they sent me an export key.

I entered the export key into the Playstation Store, and then the purchase from within the Rock Band store successfully activated.